# Is there a Trigram functionality like pg_trgm (PostgreSQL) for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, text, similarity

I created a fuzzy search in C# for a PostgreSQL database using the `similarity()` function from the `pg_trgm` module. Now I want to port this search to a MySQL database, but MySQL has no similar trigram functionality.

Is there a way to import the pg-trgm module from PostgreSQL in MySQL or is there a similar implementation of Trigrams for MySQL?

Unfortunately I was not able to find any satisfying implementation yet.

I am reluctant to use a external search engine like Solr due to the effort of installation, maintenance and becoming acquainted with the syntax and configuration.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320698/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-substring-search-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I got here Google searching for this and there is a bit of new information I also found.

As of Mysql 5.7.6, there is built in support for using nGram in full text searches.

[Mysql team article regarding ngram searches](http://mysqlserverteam.com/innodb-full-text-n-gram-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PostgreSQL but if you are using Innodb storage engine then make the column in which you are tring to search "Full-Text" search. then you can use the following search syntax to search your contant

```
SELECT subject, MATCH (subject) AGAINST ("Find This String") AS relevance_notes
FROM yourTable
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match